# Sweep / chirp signal ends at incorrect frequency

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

I'm creating a sweep / chirp signal using matlab / octave and my ending signal seems to be ending at the wrong frequency.  How can I fix it so that the signal ends at the correct frequency.

PS: I can't use the chirp command in  octave because I'm creating a chirp / sweep signal using a specific equation.

Example code with simple equation. and plot of problem

```
%test sweep / chirp

clear all,clc
freq1=20; %start freq
freq2=200; %end freq
fs=44100;
dur=1; %duration of signal in seconds

t = linspace(0,2*pi,fs*dur);

f=freq1:(freq2-freq1)/length(t):freq2-(freq2-freq1)/length(t); 
%20:(200-20)/lenght(t) :200-(200-20)/length(t)

data=sin(f.*t); %build signal
data=(data/max(abs(data))*.8); %normalize signal
wavwrite([data'] ,fs,32,strcat('/tmp/del.wav')); %export file
plot(t,data)
```

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1

[image]

Comment: You are doing a mathematical error. If your wave starts at sin(0) and ends at sin(t*200) the total number of cycles is fixed and corresponds to 200 hz on average, everything you do is an x-shift of the values in between.

Comment: @Daniel thanks but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code explains how to generate a frequency-variable sin wave.

```
freq1=20; %start freq
freq2=200; %end freq
dur=1; %duration of signal in seconds


freq=@(t)freq1+(freq2-freq1)/dur*t;
%another example, may help to understand the code
%dur=2
%freq=@(t)heaviside(t-1)*10+heaviside(t-1.5)*-9;
%Integerate over the time-local frequency, gives the average frequency until t which later on gives the sin with the right phase
%In case you don't have symbolic toolbox, integrate manually. For the given numbers Ifreq=@(x)x.*(x.*9.0+2.0)
Ifreq=matlabFunction(int(freq(sym('x'))));
%Defining wave function based on `Ifreq`
wave=@(t)(sin(Ifreq(t)*2*pi));
t=0:.00001:dur;
plot(t,wave(t));
```

Comment: your code is a bit confusing, you have several lines rem'd out along with t being defined after it's needed unless that part was left out for a reason.  And no I don't have the symbolic toolbox

Comment: @RickT: These lines are function handles. There is no need to define t before they are called.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Daniel's recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801839/7328782), this is a version that uses numerical integration, and consequently doesn't require the symbolic toolbox:

```
freq1 = 20;  % start frequency
freq2 = 200; % end frequency
fs = 44100;
dur = 1;     % duration of signal in seconds

t = 0:1/fs:dur;
freqt = linspace(freq1,freq2,numel(t));
ifreqt = cumsum(freqt)/fs;
data = sin(2*pi*ifreqt);
plot(t,data);
```