# FFT shows two time bigger frequency -- why?

Tags: matlab, fft, scilab

```
t=[0:1/4000:10];    
fk1=[0:300/size(t,2):300];    
vysk_f=fk1(1:40000);    
t=t(1:40000);    
arg = vysk_f.*t;    
sv=sin(%pi*2*arg);    
cv=cos(%pi*2*arg);    
s2= sv+cv;    
vys_sig= s2;
```

And then I do `fft`, with `Fs=4000`  and `L=4000`, for ten times, a the frequency goes from 0 to `600Hz` on frequency spectrum instead of `0` to `300Hz`.

```
fs = 4000;
L = 4000;
f = fs* ( 0 : (L / 2 )) / L;
for i = 1:2
  for j = 1:10
    fft_data=fft(vys_sig((4000*j)-3999:4000*j)); 
    subplot(2,1,1);
    a = gca();
    delete(a.children);
    plot(f,abs(fft_data(1:size(f, '*'))));
    subplot(2,1,2);
    plot(vysk_f);
    sleep(500);
  end
end
```

[image]

The picture is where the fft ends

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your code cannot be run. What do those `%` mean? Also, post code that reproduces the problem with `fft`

Comment: sorry i use scilab... and pi is defined like this

Comment: fs = 4000;
L = 4000;

f = fs* ( 0 : (L / 2 )) / L;
for i = 1:2

    for j = 1:10
        fft_data=fft(vys_sig((4000*j)-3999:4000*j));
        subplot(2,1,1);
        a = gca();delete(a.children);
        plot(f,abs(fft_data(1:size(f, '*'))));
        subplot(2,1,2);
        plot(vysk_f);
        sleep(500);   
    end
end

Comment: Adam, I’ve added this code into your question. Next time, please >[edit]< the question yourself to improve it. Comments are not meant to last long, we like having everything that is relevant in the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: Is `size(f, '*')` also a SciLab thing or is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry Cris, yea thing, it give you a size of vector f

Comment: Also, thank you for being so responsive! Sometimes people post a question and then leave for the rest of the day... :)

Comment: Thx Cris, i just want to solve this, I'm getting crazy about it

Comment: Adam, if you plot your signal `vys_sig`, and overlay it with a `cos(2*pi*t)`, and zoom in on the end of that, towards the 300Hz side, you'll see that your signal has twice the frequency. It turns out that you cannot build a chirp in this way. See the duplicate question, it is exactly the same problem. The answer requires the symbolic toolbox, not sure if you have that on SciLab too, but you can replace that with numeric integration too.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but i dont know if i understand, so i should integrate the generated frequency  `vysk_f` and with Integrated frequency make the sin and cos ?

Comment: Im confused :( Can you try to implement it in scilab please ? @Cris Luengo

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Scilab. I have written a quick MATLAB code (hopefully it works in Scilab too) under the duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51070577/7328782). (I would appreciate if you could accept the duplicate, since we'd rather not have identical questions hanging around. Thanks!)